# On Android, is camera `autofocus` a feature that is required?

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

Sample projects on https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android shows

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

but the default value for required is automatically `true`

This lessens the number of supported devices, it's not much but I'd still like my app to show up because I'm not really making use of autofocus

I can easily override this with `tools:replace="required"`, but is this okay?